# Override base class field in Odoo

Tags: attributes, odoo, odoo-8

I have to make Purchase Order Line as editable in Odoo 8. Currently, the field order_line in Purchase.Order Model has modifier as below:

```
'order_line': fields.one2many('purchase.order.line', 'order_id', 'Order Lines',
                                  states={'approved':[('readonly',True)],
                                          'done':[('readonly',True)]},
                                  copy=True)
```

So the states is readonly if approved or done. I want to remove this. I tried with below:

```
<field name="order_line" position="attributes">
     <attribute name="readonly">0</attribute>        
</field>
```

Also,

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="readonly">0</attribute>
</xpath>
```

But It does not work.

Please help

Thanks,

## UPDATE:

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
'''
classdocs
'''
_name = 'purchase.order'
_inherit = 'purchase.order'

total_cases = fields.Integer('Total Cases', default=None)
appointment_number = fields.Char('Appointment Number', default=None)

order_line = fields.One2many('purchase.order.line', 'order_id', 'Order Lines', copy=True)
```

I overrided the field order_line as above, But nothing happens

Comment: Try redefining the field in your module and remove the 'state' part from it.

Comment: Hi Hardik, This did not worked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just inherit from the model and define the field again to override it, then you can remove `states` totally

```
from openerp import fields, models

class custom_purchase_order(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'purchase.order'

    order_line = fields.One2many('purchase.order.line', 'order_id', 'Order Lines', states={}, copy=True)
```

Comment: it should, can you edit your question and show exactly how you're doing it...i also made an edit to my answer

Comment: Hi danidee, i tried xpath also, did not worked. also edited my question with override in field

Comment: Remove the `_name` definition from your model...it should be exactly like mine with just `_inherit` specified

Comment: Hi danidee, tried by removing _name, still not working

Comment: i've made another edit....it's working now, you have to override every aspect of the field to override it properly....so you have to set `states` to an empty `{}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122837/discussion-between-danidee-and-user280960).